# CSV rendering of page doesn't handle newline character within same field

Tags: csv, moqui

Moqui supports a superb feature to render any page in different formats. If I render the following code in CSV format and suppose the description field contains newline(i.e. enter key) character, then it shows it correctly in form-list but in CSV it changes the current row. I think it should not behave like this.

```
<form-list name="communicationDetail" list="communicationDetailList">
    <field name="communicationEventId"><default-field><display/></default-field></field>
    <field name="description"><default-field><display/></default-field></field>
</form-list>
```

Please help me how that newline character can be ignored while rendering data in CSV. I think it should

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV output for XML Screen is done with the DefaultScreenMacros.csv.ftl file. There is a macro at the top of the file called csvValue that does the minimal encoding. More could certainly be done there, to match whatever the parser you are using will work with.